# Jenkins :- How to use zentimestamp-plugin to get build execution time

Tags: jenkins, html-email, jenkins-plugins

I have installed zentimestamp-plugin and trying to get build execution time in email notifications using Zentimestamp env variable `BUILD_TIMESTAMP` using following ways but not able to get actual time stamp value

1. ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}
2. $BUILD_TIMESTAMP
3. BUILD_TIMESTAMP

Also, i haven't found any documentation in [plugin homepage](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin).

How can I get proper build time through email ?

Ref :- https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26520

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you select `'Change date pattern for the BUILD_TIMESTAMP (build timestamp) variable'` and supply a `'Date and Time Pattern'`.

I believe if you do not select that option, the variable does not get expanded.

I set a value for 'Date and Time pattern as `'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss'` and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks @malcolm. It would be great help if author add litle description here ? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ZenTimestamp+Plugin

Comment: Exactly what i need! Setting up the pattern resolved my problem! tks

Answer (score 0):

Just for more information this plugins are very helpful

You can specify any pattern that you want except some special characters e.g. `t, T, r, R, H ...`

```
'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss'

'yyyy-MM-dd :- HH:mm'
```

and many more combinations are possible.

Comment: The plugin uses [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Javadoc has all available letters and several examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide a default `BUILD_TIMESTAMP` pattern in the system configuration, under "Global properties" so you don't have to do it in all jobs separately.

The patterns configured under individiual projects are actually overrides for this default. That's why they are labeled `Change date pattern...`